# Не открывается видео в webview приложении андроид на весь экран. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android, webview

Кто поможет исправить? У меня не получилось.... А вебвью приложение очень хочется.
Весь код не удалось поместить сюда, поэтому вот ссылка https://pastebin.com/h3BpNfMH

```
  private void doWebViewPrint(String ss) {
    print_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        //use Service Worker
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            print_page(view,view.getTitle(),false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ссылка протухнет однажды и вопрос станет бессмысленным. Постарайтесь настолько сократить код, оставив только самое необходимое чтобы он поместился в вопрос. По сути проблемы - нужно больше деталей. Все видео не работают или только на каком-то конкретном сайте? Может проблема на сайте?

Comment: На всех сайтах видео не раскрывается на полный экран.

Comment: Попробуйте ответы отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview/56186877#56186877